# Getting Phone build and Spec details - Android

Tags: android

I have an Application in where am getting the Android smart phone's Build number, version number and manufacturer details. The APP is crashing in few devices in this section for my Users. Is it like few OEM does't allow to get the device details to take programmatically? It's happening more with HTC in USA

Comment: please add the logcat error details

Comment: I don't have any logcat details. This issue is happening only for our users who were in USA. Its working good in all the devices i have in India.

Comment: Can you obtain details? What Build methods are you using? You should be getting a stack trace from crashes on the play store console anyway.

Comment: Ya I understand but mine is a confidential App and is not exposed to all by uploading in Play store. We have our own Play store.